# grid-template-columns и grid-column

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Допустимо ли применять к одному блоку сразу `display: grid`, `grid-template-columns` и `grid-column`?

**Пример**:

```
.product {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

// Можно ли делать вот так?
.product > .gallery {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column: span 1;
}

.product > .gallery > img:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: span 4;
}

.product > .gallery > img {
    grid-column: span 1;
}
```

Comment: Да, можно. Это и есть вопрос?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov похоже даже grid-column указывать необязательно, достаточно grid-template-columns. Верно?

Comment: Сейчас напишу вам полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, так делать можно. Надеюсь вы понимаете, что в гриде есть грид-контейнер (grid container) и его непосредственные дочерние элементы (grid items). CSS свойства принадлежат либо к группе свойств контейнера, которые будут работать только на грид-контейнерах (элементах со свойством `display: grid`), либо к свойствам дочерних элементов и будут применяться только к "деткам". Если у элемента нет свойства `display: grid`, то свойства контейнера будут игнорироваться, если у непосредственного родителя нет свойства `display: grid`, то свойства родителей будут игнорироваться.

Сами элементы грида (grid items), могут быть и вложенным грид-контейнером (grid container).
Указывая свойства `display: grid` мы делаем элемент грид-контейнером и его непосредственные дочерние элементы становятся элементами грида (grid items), но эти дочерние элементы также могут быть грид-контейнерами.

Свойства `grid-template-columns` и `grid-column` очень разные, поэтому их можно применять вместе. `grid-template-columns` можно применять только к контейнерам и говорит о том в какие колонки надо помещать "деток" и работает только для непосредственных деток. Свойство `grid-column` можно применять только к "деткам" и будет работать только указывая явно колонку "ребёнка" относительно родителя и/или кол-во занимаемых колонок.

### Как это будет работать в данном случае?

- `display: grid` делает и `.product`, и `.gallery` грид-контейнерами, при этом `.gallery` будет вложенным.
- `grid-template-columns` задаёт наличие колонок для "деток", то есть `.product` будет содержать две колонки, а `.gallery` — четыре, но это, как ожидается, отразиться только на детках.
- `grid-column` задаёт позицию элемента отностильно контейнера и/или, для `.gallery` будет рассчитываться относительно `.product`, для элементов `img` относительно `.gallery`. Вообще значение `grid-column: span 1`, возможно, что довольно бесполезно, так как оно задаёт позицию по умолчанию, а элементы и так по умолчанию занимают одну колонку. Есть хотите обнулить любое свойство, то есть глобальное значение `initial`.

Comment: Относительно непосредственных детей можно сделать оговорку насчёт `display: contents`